# Нераспространенное предложение

Tags: синтаксис, грамматика, сказуемые

Какое из предложений **нераспространенное** :

"Она мечтала стать актрисой", "Расцвело незаметно"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Она мечтала стать актрисой. - нераспространенное. Состоит из грамматической основы: Она -подлежащее, мечтала стать актрисой -  осложненное составное именное сказуемое.

В примере "Рассвело незаметно" - представлен второстепенный член предложения - обстоятельство.

Answer (score 3):

> Какое из предложений нераспространенное?

ПЕРВОЕ. ***Мечтала стать актрисой*** -- осложнённая форма составного именного сказуемого.